# Stata esttab: Don't show row with name of estimator

Tags: stata

I'm using the Stata estout package to produce output tables. I want the output to not show the list of "rho" in the header (see screenshot). How can I instruct Stata to not show it?

```
estpost corr var1 var2 var3 var4, matrix
esttab, unstack noobs nonum not title("Pairwise correlations of traditional variables") cells(rho(fmt(2)))
```

(I cannot post a image, but here is a link to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/907Qq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `collabels` option:

```
esttab, unstack noobs nonum not collabels("") title("my title") cells(rho(fmt(2)))
```

Recall that `esttab` is a wrapper for `estout`, so you can find reference to that option under `help estout`.